# how to extract prediction response from a model that include both factor and continues variables

Tags: r, error-message

I have a glm model that includes (dependent variable ~ continues + factor).

I try to use the predict function to extract the response of the continuous variable.

```r
glm(TO~ STAB + Age)

newdata2 <-  with(ST, data.frame(STAB=rep(seq(from=min(ST$STAB), 
    to=max(ST$STAB), length.out = 100))))
newdata3 <- cbind(newdata2, predict(TO_STAB, newdata=newdata2, 
    type="response", se.fit=TRUE))
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Age' not found.
```

How can I add the factor variable to my table?

Comment: You need to add a `Age` column to `newdata2`. The `expand.grid` function might be useful to you. Also, you must use the `data` parameter of `glm` during fittting if you want to predict with new data.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.